# Cannot see Crittercism app crashes on Android

Tags: android, crittercism

I use crittercism for my app. Here is what i do to initialize Crittercism:

I only use the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and i initialize Crittercism like the following:

```
Crittercism.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "MY_APP_ID");
```

I do nothing else. 
I can see some information about app installs etc, but i cannot see crash reports. I do the following when i click a button in my app and deliberately crash the app:

```
public void onClick(){
    Integer i = null;
    i++;
}
```

But i cannot see the crash report of this situation. Can anyone tell me why? Do i need to add mappings.txt file etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It seems that in the developer console, the platform was set to IOS, i changed it to Android and i can see crash reports now.

Answer (score 0):

As the official Crittercism documentation says, you need more permissions.

Add the following permissions to your app’s AndroidManifest.xml file.

**INTERNET**
Required. Used to report data to Crittercism.

**ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE**
Optional. Allows providing network connectivity information such as carrier and network type.

**READ_LOGS**
Optional. Allows collecting logcat data to be attached to crashes and handled exceptions.

**GET_TASKS**
Optional. Allows augmenting crash reports with information on the activity running during a crash.

[Documentation](http://docs.crittercism.com/android/android.html)

You probably need "GET_TASKS" in order to have crash reports.